OIDC client created for Keycloak configuration is giving error with Liferay 7.4
I have created an oidc-client module which starts successfully but gives an error just after starting the bundle.
2024-05-31 06:10:56.193 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][BatchingBatch:139] HHH000315: Exception executing batch [org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update OAuthClientASLocalMetadata set mvccVersion=?, modifiedDate=? where oAuthClientASLocalMetadataId=? and mvccVersion=?], SQL: update OAuthClientASLocalMetadata set mvccVersion=?, modifiedDate=? where oAuthClientASLocalMetadataId=? and mvccVersion=?
2024-05-31 06:10:56.216 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][ROOT:47] bundle com.abc.xyz.portal.security.sso.oidc:1.0.0 (1630)[com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.servlet.filter.OpenIdConnectSessionValidationFilter(10965)] : The _offlineOpenIdConnectSessionManager field has thrown an exception
2024-05-31 06:10:56.221 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][ROOT:47] bundle com.abc.xyz.portal.security.sso.oidc:1.0.0 (1630)[com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.servlet.filter.OpenIdConnectSessionValidationFilter(10965)] : The _openIdConnect field has thrown an exception
2024-05-31 06:10:56.237 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][ROOT:47] bundle com.abc.xyz.portal.security.sso.oidc:1.0.0 (1630)[com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.servlet.filter.auto.login.OpenIdConnectAutoLoginFilter(10966)] : The _offlineOpenIdConnectSessionManager field has thrown an exception
2024-05-31 06:10:56.242 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][ROOT:47] bundle com.abc.xyz.portal.security.sso.oidc:1.0.0 (1630)[com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.servlet.filter.auto.login.OpenIdConnectAutoLoginFilter(10966)] : The _openIdConnect field has thrown an exception
2024-05-31 06:10:56.244 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][ROOT:47] bundle com.abc.xyz.portal.security.sso.oidc:1.0.0 (1630)[com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.servlet.filter.auto.login.OpenIdConnectAutoLoginFilter(10966)] : The _openIdConnectAuthenticationHandler field has thrown an exception

We are kind of stuck on this issue and not able to understand what this issue is reated to
